# Replicating SCP command in Shell script in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

Hi I have been given a task of copying files from a given server to local machine. Even I can do it manually using the command line but I need to write a script to automate it. I dont have any clue how to do it using shell, how to give the password which we would have done manually. I went through other posts but did not get the precise answer.

Are there better ways than using SCP command?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using `scp`, don't use passwords; use a public/private keypair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **preferred + more secure** way to do this is to [set up ssh key pairs](http://paulkeck.com/ssh/)

That being said, if there's a specific need to supply passwords as part of your shell script, you can use [pscp](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html), which is part of [putty-tools](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html):

If you are on ubuntu, you can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install putty-tools
```

(Or use equivalent package managers depending on your system)

Here's an example script of how to use `pscp`:

```
#!/bin/bash

password=hello_world
login=root
IP=127.0.0.1
src_dir=/var/log
src_file_name=abc.txt
dest_folder=/home/username/temp/

pscp -scp -pw $password $login@$IP:$src_dir/$src_file_name $dest_folder
```

This copies `/var/log/abc.txt` from the specified remote server to your local `/home/username/temp/`

Comment: The problem with having the password as text in the command invokation is that a simple `ps` would give the password to anybody who has access to the machine.  Perhaps the OP is okay with that, but they should at least be aware.